# Why does gdb hang after running?

Tags: macos, gdb

I recently installed gdb 9.1 on my mac version 10.0.1. and followed the darwin page to get the keyring set up.  Every once in a while I'm able to run gdb executable but a majority of the time it hangs right after the r command.

I'm able to run the code fine, but when I run it in gdb it prints

`[New Thread 0x2603 of process 48685]`

sometimes it will make two or three new threads but it then hangs.  I've tried compiling with both -g and -ggdb as well as setting breakpoints at the start of the code and it freezes regardless.

Its frustrating because I can't kill it with control c, control z, or kill -9 so I usually end up restarting the terminal.
I'm not quite sure how to debug this, any help is appreciated

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck resolving it?

Comment: So it was resolved for me after launching Xcode and installing the components it suggested to install.

Answer (score 2):

Every time running gdb, start with sudo:

```
sudo gdb ./main.out
```

After looking through all the solution, this works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

from this page https://timnash.co.uk/getting-gdb-to-semi-reliably-work-on-mojave-macos/

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -disable
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of [gdb bug #24069](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24069), which [I managed to fix today](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24069#c14) with [some patches](https://github.com/domq/homebrew-gdb/blob/master/Formula/gdb.rb).

1. Install gdb with `brew install --build-from-source domq/gdb/gdb`
2. [Code-sign it](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin#preview)
3. Be aware that there are currently other problems, e.g. I cannot seem to `break main`. More on that later (we hope)